# Powershell AD: counting groups in office

Tags: powershell, count, active-directory, formatting

I am having issues in my thought process. I want an output of something like
'Group Name' 'Title' 'Count' and I am able to get the 'Group Name' and 'Title' Columns but I'm not sure how to count, say, all of the repeat groups in the 'sales' title. Where my code is right now, is searching the entire column to see if it finds that group name, and if it finds that column and then it move the counter by 1 (this is wrong because it my find a group name with a different title)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

```
$allOffices = get-aduser -filter * -Properties physicaldeliveryofficename | Select-Object -ExpandProperty physicaldeliveryofficename #Selecting all offices
$uniOffices = $allOffices | Select-Object -Unique
$groups = $null
$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
$finallist = @()
$count = 0


foreach ($office in $uniOffices) {   # Loop through all unique offices
    $peopleInOffice = $null
    $peopleInOffice = get-aduser -filter * -properties office | Where-Object office -eq $office | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName  # Array of people in a certain office, selects username
    foreach ($person in $peopleInOffice){
        $groups = get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $person
        foreach($group in $groups) {
                if(($finallist.'Group Name'-contains $group.name) -and ($finallist.'Title' -contains $office)){$count++}
                $finallist+=  $group| Select-Object @{N='Group Name';E={$group.name}},@{N='Title';E={($office)}},@{N='Count';E={$count}}
        }
    }
}

$finallist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started working on your problem, and I'm unsure what you're asking.  Here's a *greatly* simplified and more efficient representation of your code:

```
$offices = Get-ADUser -Filter 'PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -like "*"' -Properties PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -Unique

$list = foreach ($office in $offices)
{
    foreach ($person in (Get-ADUser -Filter "Office -eq '$office'" -Properties Office, MemberOf))
    {
        $person.MemberOf |
            Get-ADGroup -Properties Name |
            Select-Object -Property @(
                @{
                    N = 'Group Name'
                    E = {$PSItem.Name}
                }
                @{
                    N = 'Title'
                    E = {$office}
                }
            )
    }
}
```

At the end, you have a `$list` object which is an array of `pscustomobject` objects that you can manipulate.  You can use `Group-Object` to determine how many groups there are with similar names using calculated properties, etc.

---

Using your problem statement:

> how to count all of the repeat groups in the `sales` title

```
$list | Group-Object -Property Title | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
The end goal is to get a tally of all the groups in every office (For instance say there are 2 people in an office called testOffice. One user has Internet Access, Domain User as groups and another has Restricted Internet, Domain User. I would like to have an excel sheet with columns like: Office, Group, Count. So in this case it would be testOffice Domain User 2 (and next maybe testOffice Internet Access 1))

Comment: I will update my code to show what I have changed - but I am still having issues with count. All help is appreciated!